# Filename from pathname excluding (unknown) extension

Tags: shell, filenames, basename

Having a [pathname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_267) it is possible to extract its [filename](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_170), excluding its *apriori* known extension, with [basename](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_40):

```
$ pathname="/home/paulo/paulo.pdf"
$ printf "%s\n" "$(basename $pathname .pdf)"
paulo
```

But if the extension is not known how can this be done?

Comment: Does "not known" mean it may not _have_ an extension?  In `zsh`: `$pathname:t:r`

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, it may not have an extension.

Comment: If the filename is something like `file.tar.gz`, what would you consider to be the extension?

Comment: @glennjackman extension == '.tar.gz'.

Comment: It's not always as simple as "everything after the first dot". Some project use dots as something like a namespace. See https://github.com/asciidisco/Backbone.Marionette.Handlebars

Comment: Similar: [Standard unix util to split "foo.bar.baz" into "foo.bar" + ".baz"?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/80907)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `zsh` shell:

```
$ pathname=/home/paulo/paulo.pdf
$ printf '%s\n' $pathname:t:r
paulo
```

- The `:t` modifier ("tail") extracts the last pathname component in `$pathname` (it works like `basename`).
- The `:r` modifier ("root", I suppose) extracts the bit of the filename up to the extension, if there is one.  The extension is the part of the filename that occurs after the last dot. This means that you would get an empty result for filenames like `.zshrc`.

The other related modifier are

- `:h` ("head"), which works like `dirname`, and
- `:e` ("extension"), which extracts the extension only.

Comment: Note that it's copied from `csh`. In `csh`, you'd also need `:q` to *quote* the result in case it contains SPC/TAB/NL or wildcards (`$pathname:t:r:q`).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [the shell’s parameter expansion modifiers](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
$ pathname="/home/paulo/paulo.pdf"
$ filename=${pathname##*/}
$ printf "%s\n" "$filename"
paulo.pdf
$ basename=${filename%.*}
$ printf "%s\n" "$basename"
paulo
```

`${pathname##*/}` is expanded to the contents of `pathname`, minus the longest prefix matching `*/`, *i.e.* the full path (if there is one). `${filename%.*}` is expanded to the contents of `filename`, minus the shortest suffix matching `.*`, *i.e.* the file’s extension (if there is one).

Note that this only removes the last filename component introduced by a dot; so `paulo.tar.gz` would become `paulo.tar`, not `paulo`. Strictly speaking the extension is `.gz` (it’s a compressed file, which happens to be a tarball; the `.tar` extension only becomes really meaningful once the file has been extracted).

This also fails to work correctly for extension-less dot-files, *e.g.* `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`; `basename` ends up empty. Default values can be used to handle that:

```
$ pathname="/home/paulo/.zshrc"
$ filename=${pathname##*/}
$ printf "%s\n" "$filename"
.zshrc
$ basename=${filename%.*}
$ printf "%s\n" "$basename"

$ printf "%s\n" "${basename:-$filename}"
.zshrc
```

Comment: Note that it gives the empty string for `/home/you/.zshrc` for instance.

Comment: Ah yes, nice catch @Stéphane!

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
pathname="/home/paulo/paulo.pdf"
printf "%s\n" "$(basename $pathname)" | sed "s/\..*$//"
```

Comment: This would leave `hello` from `hello.world.txt.gz`.

Comment: @Kusalananda This is true.. I will have to think some more.

Comment: It would still be a _valid_ result, but only if you specify that the filename extension is everything after the _first_ dot in the filename as this is slightly different from what's usually meant by a filename extension.